# cannot install to My Documents with Windows 10 Defender real time protection turned on

Tags: windows-10, inno-setup, windows-defender

My question: Is this a known quality of Windows 10 Defender?
I made two changes to Example1.iss which ships with INNO setup.  `DefaultDirName={userdocs}\My Program`
and add `PrivilegesRequired=lowest`. With these changes I run setup in a standard user account to install files to My Documents.  If Windows Defender Real Time Protection is turned on, I get `CreateFile failed; code 2. The system cannot find the file specified.`  I get this error even with a right-click and run with elevated privilege (although this targets the admin's My Documents folder).  If Defender is turned off, it runs fine.  I get this error even without `PrivilegesRequired=lowest`.  If run elevated, and Browse to `C:\Program Files (x86)` instead of `userdocs`, it installs with no error.  Also, if I change `userdocs` to `userappdata` it will install ok.  This makes it appear that WD RTP makes userdocs off limits, which seems needlessly overprotective, IMO.

Comment: This question is better suited for [Super User](https://superuser.com). Please post it there instead :)

Comment: Try code sign the installer.